# MouseClick event of a Form does't work

Tags: c#, mouseevent

I try to capture a mouse click event in a form
But it does't work

Partial Code as below

```
public partial class UIMessage : Form
{
    public UIMessage()
    {
    ...
    this.MouseClick += UIMessage_MouseClick;
    this.KeyDown += UIMessage_KeyDown;
    ...
    }

private void UIMessage_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        Console.WriteLine("Enter");
}

private void UIMessage_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Click");
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?

The Key down event is work well, but mouse click event is not

Comment: Oh! I have a Label on the form, is there a way let mouse click event to be captured by form even there are other control on it?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void UIMessage_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Click");
}
```

havent tried, but see if it works. use only `Click`.

Comment: The result is same. Now, I know the problem is that there is a Label control on the form, so the Label capture the mouse event. Is there a way can let mouse event transfer to the form at this situation?

Comment: why not try to put it also on the `Label_Click` ? Im sure its not the best answer. haha Not sure if there's a way like that positioning it after the form layer, something like that.